# Does the UA Beast Conclave revised ranger let you add your proficiency bonus to both the Boar companion's Tusk damage roll and its Charge damage roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, ranger, unearthed-arcana, animal-companions

I am just hoping to get some clarification on this one.

The [UA Ranger Beast Conclave](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf#page=6)'s Companion's Bond feature says:

> In addition to the areas where it normally uses its proficiency bonus, an animal companion also adds its proficiency bonus to its AC and to its damage rolls.

Does this mean if my boar companion uses a charge attack, I add proficiency damage twice (to the tusk damage and charge damage) or is it added only one time?

Just for referencing, the [boar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/boar)'s statblock says:

> ***Charge.*** If the boar moves at least 20 ft. straight toward a target and then hits it with a tusk attack on the same turn, the target takes an extra 3 (1d6) slashing damage. If the target is a creature, it must succeed on a DC 11 Strength saving throw or be knocked prone.
>
> ***Tusk.*** *Melee Weapon Attack:* +3 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. *Hit:* 4 (1d6 + 1) slashing damage.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 3):

You would only add the proficiency bonus one time.

As you have mentioned in your question:

> In addition to the areas where it normally uses its proficiency bonus, an animal companion also adds its proficiency bonus to its AC and to its damage rolls.

This means that when you roll for damage on an attack for your animal companion, you would add its proficiency bonus as a flat modifier to the total damage dealt. In the case of the **charge** attack, you are still only making one attack (the **charge** attack is an augmented **tusk** attack that does more damage) and thus would only add the proficiency bonus once.

Though keep in mind that you add this bonus for each attack made by your animal companion; it is not bound by any *once on your turn* limits.

Comment: Explaining that the charge damage is "extra" and thus part of the same damage roll as the Tusk attack would help improve this answer

Comment: You may be interested in adding the Panther's Pounce attack as an example where you can add the damage twice in a single turn. Up to you though, you've got my vote regardless.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland How do you mean? As far as I can tell pounce simply knocks a target prone and allows for a completely separate additional attack to be made. Do you mean that the bonus action attack would have the proficiency bonus added to it? (If so, I agree, as its a completely new damage roll)

Comment: Yup @Medix2, that's exactly what I mean. I think it would be a useful addition to the answer to shows a contrasting animal attack where the bonus _does_ take effect.